# How to make Web Deploy (msdeploy) deploy in a different folder?

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy

I'm trying to make a simple proof-of-concept Web Deployment scenario. My goal is to:

1. Take a folder with a few files and package them in a .zip file
2. Unpackage the .zip file in a **different** folder
3. Run a .exe from the unpacked folder (also letting the .exe know where it was unpacked).

I'm doing this on a virtual machine without an IIS installed, otherwise it wants to read IIS config for some reason, even if it doesn't need to do anything with it (and fails because it lacks administrative rights).

I have the following files:

```
C:\Temp\TheFolder\readme.txt
C:\Temp\TheFolder\MagicScript\CSTest.exe
```

The .zip package is created via a manifest:

```
<sitemanifest>
  <contentPath path="C:\Temp\TheFolder"/>
  <runCommand path="C:\Temp\TheFolder\MagicScript\CSTest.exe"/>
</sitemanifest>
```

For packaging I use the following command:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:manifest=manifest.xml -dest:package=ready.zip
```

For unpackaging I use the following command:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=ready.zip -dest:auto -replace:match=TheFolder,replace=OtherFolder
```

However MSDeploy stubbornly unpackages everything in the same `TheFolder`. The .exe file is also run not from the unpackaged folder. Rather it's copied to a temp folder and then run from there, with the current directory set to wherever I ran the deployment script from.

I also tried using a parameter instead of replace, but that still didn't have any effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

"msdeploy -verb:sync" - performs syncronization between source and destination. If you use "auto" provider - it synchronizes source with destination, so in your case at the same PC it is the same folder. "replace" parameter works only for files.

You can try the following way:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=ready.zip -dest:contentPath="C:\Temp\OtherFolder"
```

Or, if it won't work, try to use destination manifest:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=ready.zip -dest:-source:manifest=manifestDestination.xml
```

Where manifestDestination.xml is:

```
<sitemanifest>
  <contentPath path="C:\Temp\OtherFolder"/>
  <runCommand />
</sitemanifest>
```

Comment: I think there's a typo with the `-dest` parameter. Anyway, I hadn't thought about that. Still, that means that I need to ship TWO files - the .ZIP and the target manifest, right? Plus, the target manifest will need to be modified on the target computer...

Comment: Yes, if you use second approach, then you need two files. That depends on how you are shipping the project. If you have multiple computers, each one will need its own directory, then it would be the problem, But if each computer will have 'OtherFolder', then it is easier to build the package at the 'OtherFolder' instead of 'TheFolder'. Any way, for web deployment, I would recommend to use standard WebDeploy feature.

Comment: My company is making a product which is an intranet website (basically a web frontend for our flagship ERP application). There are many clients who use it. I want an automated installer, so that the website can be installed and upgraded automatically, without human intervention. Thus my need to specify (via command line or otherwise) many parameters for a single package.