# TFS Release Task to Deploy a Web Deploy Package to specific directory

Tags: tfs, msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've been digging for hours and i haven't been able to find what i would think is a pretty common scenario.

I am attempting to deploy a Web Deploy Package to my existing Web Site\Web App via a TFS Release.  The location of my existing Web Apps is mapped to a different drive.  My source code on my web server is not in C:\inetpub lets say its in D:\MyFiles.

I'm open to using any TFS task to do this.  It seems like my two options are:

1. Run Batch Script - point to myApp.deploy.cmd
2. WinRm IIS Web App Deployment

I've seen lots of examples of overriding the computer name via the setParamater file but I have not seen one example of how to set the target path for the package?

Again, i want to deploy a web package via a TFS release to D:\MyFiles.  I've created the package and it deploys locally to c:inetpub, I would assume if I can get it to deploy to a specified Target location locally then when I run that same. CMD file from TFS release it will use that location on the deploy to server.

UPDATE:
So... this just started working.  I'm not sure what the issue was but the WinRm Task didn't do the deploy on Friday but did the deploy on Monday.  I'm thinking it may have been related to a FQDN for the server path?  Honestly I'm not sure what fixed it or what to do with this post?  The answer below by @Andy may help someone so I won't delete it.  That link is a good one and it showed me how to perform IIS configuration with Web Deploy.

Thanks in advance, 
Greg

Comment: This post looks similar but it was unanswered.  Its not exactly what i want but its close.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330841/how-to-make-web-deploy-msdeploy-deploy-in-a-different-folder

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to change the physical path of an IIS site/app using MSDeploy.

Just try adding an additional command (appcmd) to the MSDeploy package manifest to change the physical path of the IIS site during the deployment:

```
<runcommand path="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set app /app.name:&quot;Default Web Site/app12&quot; /&#91;path='/'&#93;.physicalPath:C:\temp\app12" waitInterval="5000"/>
```

Refer to this article for details: 
[WebDeploy/MSDeploy Quick TIP: Change IIS Site/APP Physical Path with MSDeploy](https://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/06/28/webdeploymsdeploy-quick-tip-change-iis-siteapp-physical-path-with-msdeploy/)

Comment: I'm working on it now, thanks for the response, i will definitely get back to you.  We had a sprint review and planning over the last couple of days so i've been stuck in a meeting room :)  Thanks again. Greg

Comment: After working on this it seems like this is more for iis setup than deployment to the actual location. But it does seem like the winrm task is working l, I'm still digging, I'll update I  a bit.

Comment: @gperrego Any udpate?